# .htaccess URL rewrite not work for "?" symbol as data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, symbols

I want to pass this string through URL ($_GET) to my php file.

> 7dDirSxvHg9h6Z4gHX9oo29SuN8k4dXV?Authority=000000000000000000000000000070816609&Status=OK

this is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(.*)$    index.php?page=$1&$2=$3    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$   index.php?page=$1   [NC,L]
```

But when I open this url :

> example.com/callback/Data/7dDirSxvHg9h6Z4gHX9oo29SuN8k4dXV?Authority=000000000000000000000000000070816609&Status=OK

The var_dump code show this string:

```
array(2) { ["page"]=> string(8) "callback" ["Data"]=> string(32) "7dDirSxvHg9h6Z4gHX9oo29SuN8k4dXV" }
```

Any character after ? symbol removed. Which part of my code is incorrect?

Comment: Use `QSA` flag for appending previous query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to remain in the query string, you need to use a `QSA` flag in your rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(.*)$    index.php?page=$1&$2=$3    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$   index.php?page=$1   [NC,L,QSA]
```